# Issues when trying to utilize Winreg for changing Proxy settings on windows 8.1 - python 3

Tags: python-3.x

So, I am trying to change the proxy settings via python 3. I normally have no issues running this code on my win 7/win 10 devices, but for what ever reason I can not get it to run at all on windows 8.1.

I have looked rather hard and have found one thread here talking about how if Python 3 is 32 bit and you are on a 64 bit device this can cause this type of issue. I am on windows 8 64 bit computer and am running python 3.5 64 bit though, so I don't think this is my issue.

Here is the code:

```
import winreg

INTERNET_SETTINGS = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
    r'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings',
    0, winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)

def set_key(name, value):
    _, reg_type = winreg.QueryValueEx(INTERNET_SETTINGS, name)
    winreg.SetValueEx(INTERNET_SETTINGS, name, 0, reg_type, value)

set_key('ProxyEnable', 1)
set_key('ProxyServer', u'proxy:port')
```

When I attempt to run this code I receive the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\clay\Desktop\prox_test.py", line 12, in <module>
    set_key('ProxyServer', u'proxy:port')
  File "C:\Users\clay\Desktop\prox_test.py", line 8, in set_key
    _, reg_type = winreg.QueryValueEx(INTERNET_SETTINGS, name)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I have removed my proxy server info for security reasons, rest assured my original code has the proxy server/port written in the code instead of proxy:port.

I am quite stumped at this point, I have verified that the folder does exist in my registry and that the pathway is correct, and as I've said, this code runs no problems on my other devices.

Thank you have a nice day

Comment: My PC is 64bit Win 8.1 too, and I haven't changed proxy setting. In my registry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings` there's no `ProxyServer` key (though `ProxyEnable` exists), so running your code in 64bit Python 3.5.2 returns error. Did you really check the KEY (not 'folder') `ProxyServer` exists? You can check `reg query "hkcu\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\internet settings"` in `cmd`.

Comment: Interesting, you are right, I see the same thing. There is no "ProxyServer" key, but there are a few that pertain. Trying something now

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, Sangbok Lee you are right, I see the same thing. There is no "ProxyServer" key, but there are a few that pertain.

I have seen others have this issue and no answers in the thread so I will go ahead and answer.

I fixed this by accessing regedit and adding a new string named "ProxyServer" and added my proxy:port to the "value" space when modifing it. It works like a charm. Thanks Sangbok! have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to query a key that doesn't exist

```
_, reg_type = winreg.QueryValueEx(INTERNET_SETTINGS, name)
```

What I did when I had this problem was to pass key type as a parameter to the function:

```
def set_key(name, value, type):
    winreg.SetValueEx(INTERNET_SETTINGS, name, 0, type, value)
```

Then I call the function like

```
set_key('ProxyEnable', 1, winreg.REG_DWORD)
set_key('ProxyServer', sys.argv[2], winreg.REG_SZ)
```

You can find the full code here https://github.com/serkyron/win-proxy
Call it as follows: `python proxy.py "on" "socks=hostname:port"`

I also wrapped proxy.py into js code. Available at https://github.com/serkyron/proxy-setter

Usage:

```
const {setProxy} = require("proxy-setter");

setProxy("on", "socks=host:port")
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Proxy changed");
  });

setProxy("off")
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Proxy disabled");
  });
```